# How to get weak instrument test from instrument variables in modelsummary in R?

Tags: r, modelsummary

How can I get the weak instrument F-test statistic in `modelsummary`?

```
data(mtcars)
library(ivreg)

iv_model <- ivreg(mpg ~ qsec + cyl + drat | disp | wt, data = mtcars)
summary(iv_model, diagnostics = TRUE)

Call:
ivreg(formula = mpg ~ qsec + cyl + drat | disp | wt, data = mtcars)


Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) 23.28560   20.84029   1.117  0.27370   
disp        -0.05730    0.02053  -2.791  0.00953 **
qsec         0.20443    0.59223   0.345  0.73263   
cyl          0.88477    1.52033   0.582  0.56542   
drat         0.25095    2.19015   0.115  0.90962   

Diagnostic tests:
                 df1 df2 statistic  p-value    
Weak instruments   1  27     19.96 0.000127 ***
Wu-Hausman         1  26     13.87 0.000956 ***
Sargan             0  NA        NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The `metrics = "all"` option does show the Wu-Hausman and Sargan test by default.

```
library(modelsummary)
modelsummary(iv_model, metrics = "all")
```

Comment: The goodness-of-fit statistics are extracted by the `performance` package. You could open a feature request on [their Github repository](https://github.com/easystats/performance) to ask for this. Alternatively, you can easily add new statistics in `modelsummary` by following the detailed instructions in the vignette: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#new-models-and-custom-statistics

Comment: Can you point me to the specific section? Is this Adding new information to existing models ?

Comment: See my answer with cool new changes to the development version which makes this much easier. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modelsummary` includes a simple mechanism to add any goodness-of-fit statistics to tables. Search for `glance_custom` on this page for detailed instructions and examples: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html

In the specific case of `ivreg`, a contributor just added functionality to the `performance` and `modelsummary` packages to make this much easier. Install the development versions of both packages:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("easystats/performance")
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

Restart `R` completely for the change to take effect. Then,

```r
library(ivreg)
library(modelsummary)

iv_model <- ivreg(mpg ~ qsec + cyl + drat | disp | wt, data = mtcars)

gm <- transform(modelsummary::gof_map, omit = FALSE)
modelsummary(iv_model, gof_map = gm, metrics = "all")
```

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 23.286 |
|  | (20.840) |
| disp | -0.057 |
|  | (0.021) |
| qsec | 0.204 |
|  | (0.592) |
| cyl | 0.885 |
|  | (1.520) |
| drat | 0.251 |
|  | (2.190) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.655 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.604 |
| AIC | 182.7 |
| BIC | 191.5 |
| RMSE | 3.48 |
| Weak IV F-stat | 20.0 |
| Weak IV p | 0.000 |
| Sigma | 3.793 |
| Wu-Hausman | 13.869 |
| Wu-Hausman (p) | 0.001 |

Comment: Vincent did something change? I tried this again on another computer and it didn't work anymore (install from github + restart R). I get a `Sigma` but no F-stat or Wu-Hausman with the exact same code.

Comment: No, nothing should have changed. What version does `sessionInfo()` tell you is loaded?

Comment: modelsummary_1.3.0 and performance_0.10.3

Comment: Right, that's not the development version from github, which has a number like 1.3.0.9008. Your install didn't work.